# Images not displaying correctly in Angular component due to CSS rules: How to resolve?

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

I'm following a freeCodeCamp tutorial on YouTube (here's the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZniVgo8U7ek&t=651s) to create a Memory game with html, css and vanilla js. Now, I want to do it with Angular 14 but I'm having some problems with (I think) CSS. I have two components, app-board and app-card (down below you'll find the code of each component). The result to achieve is a board filled with covered cards (a 3x4 grid). I don't understand why if I put everything inside app-board it works fine but if I separate the card into its own component, this is not rendered correctly (I don't see the card background image, and the components are overlapped).

Here's the working version where everything runs inside app-board (something similar to the video):

**HTML**

```
<section class="memory-game">
  <div class="memory-card">
    <img class="front-face" src="../../../assets/img/aurelia.svg">
    <img class="back-face" src="../../../assets/img/js-badge.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="memory-card">
    <img class="front-face" src="../../../assets/img/aurelia.svg">
    <img class="back-face" src="../../../assets/img/js-badge.svg">
  </div>

  <!-- And so on with other cards... -->
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.memory-game {
  width: 640px;
  height: 640px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 2px solid lime;
}

.memory-card {
  width: 25%;
  height: 33.333%;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.front-face,
.back-face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #1C7CCC;
}
```

The **TS** file contains just the code that you find everytime you create a new component with cli.

This is the version with two components. The **board** is:
**HTML**

```
<section class="memory-game">
  <app-card [frontImgPath]="'../../../assets/img/aurelia.svg'"
    [backImgPath]="'../../../assets/img/js-badge.svg'"></app-card>
  <app-card [frontImgPath]="'../../../assets/img/aurelia.svg'"
    [backImgPath]="'../../../assets/img/js-badge.svg'"></app-card>

  <app-card [frontImgPath]="'../../../assets/img/vue.svg'"
    [backImgPath]="'../../../assets/img/js-badge.svg'"></app-card>
  <app-card [frontImgPath]="'../../../assets/img/vue.svg'"
    [backImgPath]="'../../../assets/img/js-badge.svg'"></app-card>

  <app-card [frontImgPath]="'../../../assets/img/angular.svg'"
    [backImgPath]="'../../../assets/img/js-badge.svg'"></app-card>
  <app-card [frontImgPath]="'../../../assets/img/angular.svg'"
    [backImgPath]="'../../../assets/img/js-badge.svg'"></app-card>

  <!-- So on for the other cards -->
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.memory-game {
  width: 640px;
  height: 640px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 2px solid lime;
}
```

still the default **TS**.

The **app-card** component is:
**HTML**

```
<div class="memory-card">
  <img class="front-face" [src]="frontImgPath">
  <img class="back-face" [src]="backImgPath">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.memory-card {
  width: 25%;
  height: 33.333%;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.front-face,
.back-face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #1C7CCC;
}
```

**TS**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-card',
  templateUrl: './card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card.component.css']
})
export class CardComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() frontImgPath!: string;
  @Input() backImgPath!: string;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

In both cases I'm using this global **style.css**

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #060AB2;
}
```

Things (even stupids) that I've tried and haven't worked:

1. Put the Card component's folder inside the Board component's folder
2. Using the **ViewEncapsulation.None**
3. Using the Grid layout
4. From Google Chrome's console, I've inspected the element and if I remove the **width** property I can see the card back, but it is very big. Increasing and decreasing width doesn't produce any change.
5. Check if the image path is correct. I was sure about it because I've copy/pasted it from the working version
6. Check the console for errors but none showed

If you need more details, just tell me. Since this account is new I have very limited functionalities on it. I'll try to do my best. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Try changing your image paths to just start with /assets

Comment: @MikeOne I'll try but I don't think this will work because in the working version I see the images and the path is exactly the same. Also the intellisense displays the various folder while I write the path, so I think it's correct. EDIT: As I wrote, if I remove the widt property from the non-working version, I can see the images but they're very big